# Error trying to insert key value into a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having problems trying to insert a key value (which I generate) into a table (jml_acymailing_subscriber).

```
$generateKey = md5(substr($email[1],0,strpos($email[1],'@')).rand(0,10000000));
$subid = 3603;
$sql2 = "UPDATE jml_acymailing_subscriber SET key='$generateKey', WHERE subid='$subid'";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2,$con) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
```

The key type is:

```
TYPE -->  varchar(250)  
ORDENATION --> utf8_general_ci
NULL --> yes
DEFAULT --> NULL
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Fatal error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'key='15e3e092aa8672a6f7ad3e8a5a1db537', WHERE subid='3603'' at line 1 in 
/public_html/bootstrap3/donarAltaCatala.php on line 136
```

I have no problem inserting values like `userid`, `name`, `created` or any other ones. Any one knows where is the problem? I'm starting in PHP/SQL...

Thank you! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`key` is reserverd word in mysql, so can use  backticks **key**

```
$sql2 = "UPDATE jml_acymailing_subscriber SET `key`='$generateKey' WHERE subid='$subid'";
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: or, better idea, change the name of that column.

Answer (score 0):

Two things;

`KEY` is a [reserved word in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), so to use it as a field/table name it needs to be quoted with backticks (`)

...and...

```
"UPDATE jml_acymailing_subscriber SET key='$generateKey', WHERE subid='$subid'"
                                                        ^ erroneous comma
```

Corrected, that would result in;

```
"UPDATE jml_acymailing_subscriber SET `key`='$generateKey' WHERE subid='$subid'"
```

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing why the downvote so I could improve the answer.

Comment: +1.. probably the user expected a full completed answer and not a suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

remove the , after `key='$generateKey'` so that it looks like:

```
"UPDATE jml_acymailing_subscriber SET key='$generateKey' WHERE subid='$subid'";
```